# Error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Im a newbie and got this project from a friend that keeps telling me Error “Object reference not set to an instance of an object.” Could someone kindly help with this
line 15

```
Line 13:         {
Line 14:            ViewBag.ResumeId = firstResume.ResumeId;
Line 15:            var firstResume = _context.Resumes.FirstOrDefault();
Line 16:             return View(firstResume);            
Line 17:         }
```

Comment: `_context.Resumes` is null. That much you could have gotten through the debugger. Now, *why* it's null, is another matter and can't be determine from the code you've provided.

Comment: Actually, I think your code paste is off somehow. You're calling `firstResume` before it's defined. Which should give you a compiler error long before you get the runtime error that brought you here.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. Heres the full code paste

    namespace LiveCV.Controllers
    {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        LiveCV.Models.LiveCVContext _context = new     
    Models.LiveCVContext();

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var firstResume = _context.Resumes.FirstOrDefault();
                ViewBag.ResumeId = firstResume.ResumeId;
                return View(firstResume);            
            }

            public ActionResult About()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Hi there @ChrisPratt heres the full code   http://pastebin.com/HsJc4jfj

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure if it's still line 15, but I would think that the error is actually originating from the line:

```
ViewBag.ResumeId = firstResume.ResumeId;
```

Most likely, `firstResume` is null since the result of `FirstOrDefault` will either be an instance or null. You need to need to always check that you actually got something back before trying to use it:

```
var firstResume = _context.Resumes.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstResume != null)
{
    ViewBag.ResumeId = firstResume.ResumeId;
}
```

However, if it's an object that your view can't live without, it's more typical to do something like:

```
if (firstResume == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

And then you can use the object as you please, since a 404 response would have already been returned if it was null.